# How to add one-to-many correctly with an array field in sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, associations, associative-array

So I have a user which can many many modules. The user table has a module fields which is an array of module_id. I think I should do a one to Many association. Is it correct?
so I did the associations like this:

```
User.belongsTo(Module, {
    as: "user_module",
    foreignKey: "module_id",
    sourceKey: "module",
    constraints: false, 
});

Module.hasMany(User, {
    sourceKey: "module_id",
    foreignKey: "module",
    constraints: false, 

});
```

The user table has these two properties:

```
  user_id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
    module: {
                type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.UUID),
                allowNull: true, 
            },
```

When I try to add a new user it creates one and  I can add the module_id as an array but when I try to query the user_module is null.
I query the user like this:

```
 await db.user.findAll({
            raw: true, include: [ 
                {
                    model: Module,
                    as: 'user_module'
                }
            ]
        })
```

Where am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?